# How to overwrite data in text file in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, toplevel

I am creating a program with tkinter which comes with a default name and password stored in a text file. After login you need to open the `Toplevel` window and type in the name and password you want to use in your subsequent logins. I have defined my variables but if I want to overwrite the text file I receive the below:

> Error "NameError: name 'e1' is not defined"

Which I know I have defined.

```
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *


now = open("pass.txt","w+")
now.write("user\n")
now.write("python3")
now.close()


def login_in():
    with open("pass.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
        name = new[0].rstrip()
        password = new[1].rstrip()
    if entry1.get() == name and entry2.get() == password:
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")


def change_login():
    ch = Toplevel(root)
    ch.geometry('300x300')
    e1 = Entry(ch, width=20).pack()
    e2 = Entry(ch, width=20).pack()
    sb = Button(ch, text="save", command=save_changes).pack()

def save_changes():  # function to change data in the txt file
    data = e1.get() + "\n " + e2.get()
    with open("pass.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)


root= Tk()
log = Toplevel()


root.geometry("350x350")
log.geometry("200x200")

entry1 = Entry(log)
entry2 = Entry(log)
button1 = Button(log, text="Login", command=login_in) #Login button

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
button1.pack()

label = Label(root, text="welcome").pack()
butt = Button(root, text="change data in file", command=change_login).pack()

root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `e1` is a variable which is local to `change_login()` however you are calling it in `save_changes()` where it is not present. So it's throwing this error up to tell you that the variable does not exist in that local space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a few options here but in general you have 2 major issues.

The first issue is the use of `.pack()` after the creation of your `e1` and `e2` entry fields. This is a problem for the `get()` method as the geometry manager will return `None` if you pack this way. The correct method is to create the widget first with `e1 = Entry(ch, width=20)` and then pack it on the next line with `e1.pack()` this will allow `get()` to work on `e1`.

The second issue is the matter of local variables vs global variables. You have created `e1` and `e2` inside of the function `change_login()` and without telling python that `e1` and `e2` are global variables it will automatically assume you want them as local variables. This means the variables are only accessible from within the function they are created in.

You have a few options and I will break them out for you.

1) The quick and dirty option is to assign `e1` and `e2` as global variables. This can be done by using `global var_name, var2_name, and_so_on` so in this case add this line to the top of your `change_login():` and `save_changes()` functions:

```
global e1, e2
```

This well tell python to add `e1` and `e2` to the global name space and it will allow `save_changes()` to work with the variables in the global name space.

2) Another method is to pass the 2 variables to `save_changes()` using the button command. We will need to use `lambda` for this and we can accomplish this by adding:

```
command = lambda e1=e1, e2=e2: save_changes(e1, e2)
```

to the button created in `change_login()` and adding the 2 arguments to `save_changes()` like this:

```
save_changes(e1, e2)
```

This will work just as well as the first option and it also avoids the use of global variables.

3) A third option is to create the entire program as a class and to use class attributes to allow the variables to work with all methods within the class.

Below is an example of your code using the 1st option:

```
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *

now = open("pass.txt","w+")
now.write("user\n")
now.write("python3")
now.close()

def login_in():
    with open("pass.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
        name = new[0].rstrip()
        password = new[1].rstrip()
    if entry1.get() == name and entry2.get() == password:
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")

def change_login():
    global e1, e2
    ch = Toplevel(root)
    ch.geometry('300x300')
    e1 = Entry(ch, width=20)
    e1.pack()
    e2 = Entry(ch, width=20)
    e2.pack()
    sb = Button(ch, text="save", command=save_changes).pack()

def save_changes():  # function to change data in the txt file
    global e1, e2
    data = e1.get() + "\n" + e2.get() # removed space after \n
    with open("pass.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)

root= Tk()
log = Toplevel()
root.geometry("350x350")
log.geometry("200x200")

entry1 = Entry(log)
entry2 = Entry(log)
button1 = Button(log, text="Login", command=login_in) #Login button

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
button1.pack()

label = Label(root, text="welcome").pack()
butt = Button(root, text="change data in file", command=change_login).pack()

root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Below is an example of your code using the 2nd option:

```
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *

now = open("pass.txt","w+")
now.write("user\n")
now.write("python3")
now.close()

def login_in():
    with open("pass.txt") as f:
        new = f.readlines()
        name = new[0].rstrip()
        password = new[1].rstrip()
    if entry1.get() == name and entry2.get() == password:
        root.deiconify()
        log.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")

def change_login():
    ch = Toplevel(root)
    ch.geometry('300x300')
    e1 = Entry(ch, width=20)
    e1.pack()
    e2 = Entry(ch, width=20)
    e2.pack()
    Button(ch, text="save", command=lambda e1=e1, e2=e2: save_changes(e1, e2)).pack()

def save_changes(e1, e2):  # function to change data in the txt file
    data = e1.get() + "\n" + e2.get() # removed space after \n
    with open("pass.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(data)

root= Tk()
log = Toplevel()
root.geometry("350x350")
log.geometry("200x200")

entry1 = Entry(log)
entry2 = Entry(log)
button1 = Button(log, text="Login", command=login_in) #Login button

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
button1.pack()

label = Label(root, text="welcome").pack()
butt = Button(root, text="change data in file", command=change_login).pack()

root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Below is an example of your code converted to a class and using class attributes to avoid the use of global variables.

```
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *


class MyApp(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master
        self.master.withdraw()

        self.log = Toplevel()
        self.master.geometry("350x350")
        self.log.geometry("200x200")

        self.entry1 = Entry(self.log)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.log)
        self.button1 = Button(self.log, text="Login", command=self.login_in)

        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.button1.pack()

        Label(root, text="welcome").pack()
        Button(root, text="change data in file", command=self.change_login).pack()

    def login_in(self):
        with open("pass.txt") as f:
            new = f.readlines()
            name = new[0].rstrip()
            password = new[1].rstrip()
        if self.entry1.get() == name and self.entry2.get() == password:
            self.master.deiconify()
            self.log.destroy()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("error","login Failed")

    def change_login(self):
        ch = Toplevel(self.master)
        ch.geometry('300x300')
        self.e1 = Entry(ch, width=20)
        self.e1.pack()
        self.e2 = Entry(ch, width=20)
        self.e2.pack()
        Button(ch, text="save", command=self.save_changes).pack()

    def save_changes(self):
        data = "{}\n{}".format(self.e1.get(), self.e2.get())
        with open("pass.txt", "w") as f:
            f.writelines(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    now = open("pass.txt","w+")
    now.write("user\n")
    now.write("python3")
    now.close()

    root = Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Sierra Mountain Tech  for the corrections i realized my variables were not global  when @ Ethan Field  pointed it out so i was working around it until your posted your answers.All works fine. Thanks  again.

Comment: That was one problem but you also had a issue with `pack()` that would cause your program to fail even if you had `e11 and `e2` set up as globals. That said happy coding!

Comment: The new data typed into entry fields truly overwrite on the old but when i run  the program again and type new data at login stage am not able to login until i use the old data in the file :"user" and "python3".How can i make it to accept only new data entered into the text file at login stage and ignore the initial one i wrote to the file when i created it.

Comment: you will need to remove the `now = open("pass.txt", "w+")`, now.write()` and `now.close()` portion of your code. This will run at the start of your program every time.

Comment: yea it was not working after declaring the global variables until i applied how used your pack().Many thanks @ Mountain Tech for this

Comment: It worked when i removed it.Please what i want you to understand is that the  program has a default name and password but after login you need to change the credentials to your preferences so on your next login you need to provide the new credentials at login stage.